# Why am I getting ModuleNotFoundError after installing Negbio?

Tags: python-3.x, django, dockerfile, spacy

Building a docker image, I've installed Negbio in my Dockerfile using:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/NegBio.git xyz && \
    python xyz/setup.py install
```

When I try to run my Django application at localhost:1227 I get:

> No module named 'negbio' ModuleNotFoundError exception

When I run pip list I can see negbio. What am I missing?

Comment: Why did you clone the project even though the package is available via pip?

Comment: Also, is it possible for you to add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I tried to install but that did not work at all for me I'll post an example later today Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately resolved my issue by going to an all Anaconda environment.  Thank you for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, `It wouldn't install with pip and hence not installing via pip`.

Firstly, to make sure the https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/NegBio is properly installed via `python setup.py install`, you need to install it's dependencies via `pip install -r requirements` first. So either ways, you are doomed to have `pip` inside Docker.

For example, this is the sample `Dockerfile` that would install the `negbio` package properly:

```
 FROM python:3.6-slim

 RUN mkdir -p /apps
 WORKDIR /apps

 # Steps for installing the package via Docker:
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y git gcc build-essential
 RUN git clone https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/NegBio.git
 WORKDIR /apps/NegBio
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 RUN python setup.py install

 ENV PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH

 EXPOSE 8000

 CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

So wouldn't harm if you actually install it via `requirements.txt`

I would do it like this:

`requirements.txt` --> have all your requirements added here

```
negbio==0.9.4
```

And make sure it's installed on the fly inside the docker using `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @PhilO, IMHO, a very vague way to express the error's. While I under the error is still: `No module named 'negbio' ModuleNotFoundError exception`. Please do share the docker file contents so that one can reproduce it. Firstly the question just says: `RUN git clone https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/NegBio.git xyz && python xyz/setup.py install` and doesn't account for further steps you have tried. While I was able to import `import negbio` seamlessly and make it work in Django, it's really hard to even decode "Been there, tried that"